# Tableau: Output grouped data in different graphs

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set (let's assume it's students and scores) in Tableau.
I have used the `Rank_parcentile()` to rank them:

```
Rank_parcentile(sum([score]))
```

I then use the following code to group the students:

```
IF [percentile] > 0.8
THEN "Top 20%"
ELSEIF [percentile] <0.8 and [percentile]>0.5
THEN "Mid 30%"
ELSEIF [percentile]<-0.5 THEN "Bottom 50%"
```

This works very well and groups them as so. The problem is that sometimes I have too many students and they can't fit in a single graph reasonably.
Is there a way to divide the top 20% in one graph , the mid 30% in another and the bottom 50% in another?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: you can... create 3 sheets and combine those in dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach is put percentile on the filter shelf. Show the filter, and then interactively switch between the three groups of marks -- all on the same chart

Alternatively, you can use a similar calculation to make a trellis chart.